# <T> cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, objectmapper

I want to convert a json string to a `List<Someclass>` using jackson json library.

```
public static List<T> toList(String json, Class<T> type, ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties){

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper(objectMapperProperties);

        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, type));
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So if I pass `Attribute.class` as `type`, then it must return a `List<Attribute>`.

However, this gives me a compile time error

```
T cannot be resolved to a type
```

I guess generics part is not clear to me here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that "T" in the context of the compiler could be a type like any other.  Using letters T U V are conventions that we use for generics, but you could just as easily write List<SomeClass> instead.  In order to tell the compiler it is a generic, you have to do something to distinguish it, otherwise it is just a type that can't be resolved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you need to declare `T` first in your generic method, In your case it would be :

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(String json, Class<T> type,  ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties)
```

for more info please check oracle documentation for generic methods:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html